# How to export table after sorting in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

*I want to sort when I click on names in that order i want to download  csv e.g-Afzar,Babar,Himanshu
after sorting Himanshu,Babar,Afzar in this order I want to export csv in react{Any packages or link availiable pls share}*

Answer (score 0):

This package [react-native-csv](https://github.com/Bunlong/react-native-csv) looks cool to handle csv in react-native and this package [react-csv](https://github.com/react-csv/react-csv) to handle csv in react.

Comment: Hello P-A I have used this package earlier but isn't helping..

Answer (score 0):

you can use for excel export something like this :

```
npm install xlsx-style --save
npm install react-data-export --save
```

in return

```
const dataSet2 = [
  {
    name: "Johnson",
    total: 25,
    remainig: 16,
  },
  {
    name: "Josef",
    total: 25,
    remainig: 7,
  },
];
function ExcelSuccessReserve() {
  return (
    <ExcelFile>
  
      <ExcelSheet data={dataSet2} name="Leaves">
        <ExcelColumn label="Name" value="name" />
        <ExcelColumn label="Total Leaves" value="total" />
        <ExcelColumn label="Remaining Leaves" value="remaining" />
      </ExcelSheet>
    </ExcelFile>
  );
```